# Deployment JavaFX in the Browser trouble

Tags: java, browser, javafx

I am new in javaFX and I just can't run simple Hello World in web browser.
I follow official Oracle tutorial for hello world and after building it, jar file works perfectly. But when I try open (even from local file) .html file in web browser or .JNPL, I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKWPc.jpg

I searched all over the internet but  I couldn't find this kind of error anywhere.
I have the newest version of java (7.40). I use netBeansIDE 7.2.1 I allow everything firefox asks from my and still it doesnt work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why don't you start with checking your browser's security settings?

Comment: I looked into firefox security settings and tried to disabled everything. No result. Interesting thing is that I get the same pop up window no matter what browser do I use. It may be avast causing the trouble.

Comment: Perhaps. Or some other antivirus/firewall app. Anyway, this does not look like a JavaFX problem at all.